# AngularJS: Retrieve mysql data in electron and publish it to AngularJS scope

Tags: angularjs, node.js, electron, mysql2

I'm trying to retrieve a list of data from `mysql` database by using [electron](https://electronjs.org/docs) and bind it to a list in the controllers scope. I'm using `mysql2`. Here is my controller:

```
$scope.carList = [];
mysql.execute("SELECT * FROM cars").spread(function(results){
    $scope.carList = results;
    console.log(results);
})
```

I do get the results back, but the in the view `carList` remains empty. How can I solve this problem?

---

I just added a button to my view and bound it to a check function like this:

```
$scope.check = function(){
    console.log($scope.carList);
}
```

After  I click on the button, my list in the views gets populated. Now my question would be how can I have my list populated on the start of the controller rather than wait for an event ro make it happen?

Comment: How can you access your msql database via client application directly?

Comment: @lin, I'm using electron to build a desktop app. I just added this information to the question

Comment: You're trying to run a node module on the client and access your database from there. You can't do that, it's a node module and user's shouldn't be able to do whatever they want with your DB.. think about it!

Comment: @DominicTobias nope he is right. Please check https://electronjs.org/docs

Comment: @lin right about which part? can you run node modules in electron? Good to know, but even if you could why would you connect directly to a shared remote db from a client? In most cases that sounds very insecure!

Comment: @DominicTobias please read the documentation of electron. It's made for full stand alone software. In that way it doesnt matter. The compiled application of electron also provides the backend application. That's why it doesnt matter if the mysql connection is handled by the client or the backend. Both applications are delivered to the user as one stand alone application.

Comment: @Dominic Tobias, For now I'm onlny getting a list of cars from local database. Later on, I will use a remote database, so your comment is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `mysql.execute("").spread(fn)` promise is not a part of the AngularJS digest cycle. You did not provide enough code to fully reproduce your problem but I think by triggering a new digest cycle it should work for you. E.g. try it with `$timeout` which triggers a new digest cycle.

```
$scope.carList = [];

mysql.execute("SELECT * FROM cars").spread(function(results){
     $timeout(function () {
        $scope.carList = results;
     });
})
```

I would prefer to create a AngularJS service which handles your electron `mysql` in a nice way. You could globally apply your `$scopes` in it, right after finishing your mysql procedures which are not a part of your digest cycle.

---

#### Approach by using AngularJS promises

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $q) {


  $scope.carList = [];

  getCars.then(function(cars) {
    $scope.carList = cars;
  });


  function getCars() {

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    mysql.execute("SELECT * FROM cars").spread(function(results) {
      deferred.resolve(results);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
  }

});
```

Comment: Yes I do want to create a service only for database procedures. and your answer was quite helpful. Thank you

Comment: I'm getting an error that getCars.then is not a function